# Find, replace failing on some characters

Tags: macos, bash, unix

i'm on Mac os, and want to replace in all php files from a directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

by

```
<?php ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); ?> <!DOCTYPE html>
```

So I try this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '' s/<!DOCTYPE html>/<?php ob_start(\"ob_gzhandler\"); ?>/ {} +
```

I escaped the " but this still gives the error:

> -bash: !DOCTYPE: event not found

How should I modify this line so it will work properly ?

Comment: Use single quotes around your argument to `sed`.

Comment: `sed -i '' 's/<!DOCTYPE html>/<?php ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); ?>/'`

Comment: thanks you can create answer and I will choose it